# Estimating variable wrt dummy variables

Tags: stata

This is my assignment:

"You are going to estimate a wage equation using data in the data file dataset_wage-US.dta consisting of a sample of 1000 individuals from USA in 2008 with the following variables:

- wage=wage per hour measured in US $
- educ=years of education
- exper=years job experience after finished education.
- black=dummy variable equal to 1 if the individual is black, 0 otherwise
- female=dummy variable equal to 1 if female, 0 otherwise

The following dummies record residence regions:

- west=1 if residing in the West
- midwest=1 if residing in the Mid-west
- south=1 if residing in the South
- residing in the North-east is the reference category

Estimate a linear wage equation where you include education, race, gender and residence region variables and allow the effect of gender to depend on residence region. Report the results and interpret the coefficients."

I seriously struggle to parse the following part: "allow the effect of gender to depend on residence region."

Perhaps it's because English is a second language. What is meant here, and how do I solve it?

Comment: You highlight the instruction "allow the effect of gender to depend on residence region". Not understanding that is not a programming question, so this seems off-topic to me: I suggest you ask in a statistical or economics forum. Also, consider advice on assignment questions at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Many members here expect good faith attempts to start to answer such questions.

Answer (score 0):

You add a another variable: Femaleresidencex = (female*residencex). 
Since there are three "residences" you either add three such variables and/or generate a new variable "North-east", which is 1 IF all of other residence-varables is equal to 0.

In general: 
To allow the effect of changing D1 to depend on D2, include
the “interaction term” D1i*D2i as a regressor:
Yi = B0 + B1D1 + B2D2 + B3(D1*D2) + u